# RecyclerView Adapter return NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I want to make double recyclerview to represent rooms on each floor. but NullPointerException occurs in floorAdapter.

```
public class FloorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FloorAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public ArrayList<FloorData> floors;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public FloorAdapter(ArrayList<FloorData> floors, Context context) {
        this.floors = floors;
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.signle_floor, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new RoomAdapter(context, floors.get(position).rooms));
        holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.tvFloorNum.setText(floors.get(position).floorNum);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return floors.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        TextView tvFloorNum;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvFloors);
            tvFloorNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFloorNum);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<RoomData> rooms;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public RoomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RoomData> rooms) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rooms = rooms;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_room, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoomData room = rooms.get(position);
        holder.tvRoomNum.setText(room.roomNum);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rooms.size();
    }


    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvRoomNum;

        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvRoomNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRoomNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class RoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rvFloor;
    private FloorAdapter floorAdapter;
    private ArrayList<FloorData> floors;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_room);


        floors = prepareData();

        rvFloor = findViewById(R.id.rvFloors);

        floorAdapter = new FloorAdapter(floors, RoomActivity.this);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(RoomActivity.this);
        rvFloor.setLayoutManager(manager);
        rvFloor.setAdapter(floorAdapter);

    }

    private ArrayList<FloorData> prepareData() {
        ArrayList<FloorData> floors = new ArrayList<FloorData>();

        //첫번째 subject 추가
        FloorData floor1 = new FloorData();
        floor1.floorNum = 1;
        floor1.rooms = new ArrayList<RoomData>();

        RoomData room101 = new RoomData();
        room101.roomNum = 101;

        RoomData room102 = new RoomData();
        room102.roomNum = 102;

        RoomData room103 = new RoomData();
        room103.roomNum = 103;

        floor1.rooms.add(room101);
        floor1.rooms.add(room102);
        floor1.rooms.add(room103);


        floors.add(floor1);

        FloorData floor2 = new FloorData();
        floor2.floorNum = 2;
        floor2.rooms = new ArrayList<RoomData>();

        RoomData room201 = new RoomData();
        room201.roomNum = 201;

        RoomData room202 = new RoomData();
        room202.roomNum = 202;

        RoomData room203 = new RoomData();
        room203.roomNum = 203;

        floor2.rooms.add(room201);
        floor2.rooms.add(room202);
        floor2.rooms.add(room203);


        floors.add(floor2);


        return floors;
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".tools.RewardActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar_room"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:title="호실 등록"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvFloors"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFloorNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvRooms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRoomNumber"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat explain

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'void
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)'
> on a null object reference"

I refer to https://medium.com/@ashishkudale/android-list-inside-list-using-recyclerview-73cff2c4ea95. It's almost the same, but I don't know why the error is happening. please help me

Comment: Your RecyclerView is null. Make sure it is in the activity_room.

Comment: May I ask how to fix it?ㅠㅠㅠㅠ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things.
First, in your FloorAdapter's ViewHolder's constructor, you are finding recycler view of activity instead of that of Adapter. Change your code to,

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvRooms); //**This is rvFloors in your code**
            tvFloorNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFloorNum);
        }
```

in FloorAdapter. This will resolve your crash.

But you will experience two more crashes here

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new RoomAdapter(context, floors.get(position).rooms));
        holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.tvFloorNum.setText(floors.get(position).floorNum); // **Crash will be on this line**
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoomData room = rooms.get(position);
        holder.tvRoomNum.setText(room.roomNum);//**Crash will be on this line**
    }
```

These will happen because setText method takes String as argument but you are passing either Integer or int.

So change both these lines to

1. `holder.tvFloorNum.setText(String.valueOf(floors.get(position).floorNum));`
2. `holder.tvRoomNum.setText(String.valueOf(room.roomNum));`

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Thank you :)Thanks to your help, I solved the problem.